# Test execution of prospect Tracking completed with errors.Embedded Message: Input value 'Prospect' is not a number;java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: salesforce, enterprise-integration, boomi

I am new to Dell Boomi and now I am into New Developer Certificate path 1. While doing User Defined Map Functions I got an error message like Test execution of prospect Tracking completed with errors.Embedded Message: Input value 'Prospect' is not a number;java.lang.NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0):

Look at the profiles that you are trying to map. Either the input to that function are strings instead of numbers, or you are trying to output a string into a number element.